# Can Flume add header to data?

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I am dealing with data like:
`{"a":1,"b":2}` and I want Flume to add a header to all data like `{"header":self_define,"content":{"a":1,"b":2}}`

I read some material about Flume interceptor but it seems they can only be used to modify output path of sinks. Is there any way to achieve this or I have to develop an interceptor class by myself?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Flume Morphline Interceptor :

> Flume MorphlineInterceptor runs the transformations of a morphline on intercepted events. For example the morphline can ignore events or
>   alter or insert certain event headers using regular expression-based
>   pattern matching.